# Tomcat response mix-up

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

Have been seeing a very unique situation. Need some input.

Background: We have tomcat servers on ec2 instances with ELB. Our application is a spring application which does not use sessions cause we didn't want the load balancer to track sessions. We use cookies to identify the user. We use Memcache to store some basic session information. For the most part everything works great.

Problem: In some remote cases 0.01% of the time (we analyzed) the response is getting mixed up between the users. And the users are usually coming from the same clientIP. We know this because our application is being used extensively by schools. The client cookie and the cookie we read in the servlet matches. We are positive our application is not looking up the wrong info in the DB. But the response (the view) that is getting rendered is for another user. We know both users are logged in at the same time.

Is this something Tomcat related? Or Network related?

Controller Code:

`@RequestMapping("/kids")`

```
public ModelAndView kids(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    StudentUserSession studentUserSession = BaseController.getStudentUserSession(request);

    if(studentUserSession != null) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("kids");

        mv.addObject("studentUserSession", studentUserSession);

        return mv;

    } else {

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/signin");

    }

}
```

JSP Code:

```
var acookie = readCookie("sp_utkn");

var studentId = ${studentUserSession.studentId};

$.getJSON("/getStudentProfile", function(data){
 var sId = -1;
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if(key == 'studentId'){
    sId = value;
    }
 });
 dojo.xhrGet({
    url:"/logStudentEvent?cookie=" + acookie+"&stuId="+studentId+"&aId="+sId+"&ref="+otherInfo.join(','),
 });
  });
```

The JSON Get Call is getting the same object . aId matches with the cookie but studentId doesn't. The other data on the page are also for another user. But the cookies are consistent and accurate.

Comment: Can you post some more data to help us help you? maybe some code? how are you storing/retrieving the data from the cache?

Comment: Are you storing/using ThreadLocal based data and not properly cleaning those up?

Comment: I am using the ModelAndView to send data to the JSP view.

Comment: I am using the ModelAndView to send data to the JSP view.  
`@RequestMapping("/kids")
 public ModelAndView kids(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
 StudentUserSession studentUserSession = BaseController.getStudentUserSession(request);
 // object is coming in from Memcached/DB if the key is not present. The key is the cookie value in the request
 if(studentUserSession != null) {
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("kids");
  mv.addObject("studentUserSession", studentUserSession);
  return mv;
 } else {
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/signin");
 }
 }`

Comment: I am sorry about the formatting. Still trying to figure out the best way to put in code.

Comment: edited my original response with more data. Help!

Comment: Would you add the code fot the getStudentUserSession in BaseController?